# Create Dictionary with uneven lens

Tags: python-3.x

This may sound a bit strange or silly but I am trying to create a dictionary or lists that can be referenced. Maybe if you look at the attached pic of my Excel would give you a better understanding.

I want the values of each row to be into a dictionary with say the key as 0 and different values as under Hostname, IP, GroupName and Port. the dictionary works with just the Hostname and IP as their length is same, but  when i try to add the GroupName to the dict by using a lot of methods i found on Stackoverflow, it does not work as the length is not the same

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zEYgx.png)

Any help would be appreciated

Here is my code.

```
df = pd.read_excel("object.xlsx")

HostList =[]
IPList = []

for x in ExcelHostList:
    for hostname in x:
        if hostname not in HostList:
            HostList.append(hostname)

for ips in ExcelIPList:
    for ipadd in ips:
        if ipadd not in IPList:
            IPList.append(ipadd)

dict1 = dict(zip(HostList, IPList))
```

> > > dict1
> > >       {'test1': '1.1.1.1', 'test2': '2.2.2.2', 'test3': '3.3.3.3', 'test4': '4.4.4.4', 'test5': '5.5.5.5', 'test6': '6.6.6.6'}

I have tried with making it a dict and then trying to combine them

```
 ExcelHostList = (df["Hostname"].str.split("\n").to_dict())
 ExcelIPList = (df["IP"].str.split("\n").to_dict())
 ExcelGroupName = (df["GroupName"].to_dict())

dict2 = {z[0]: list(z[1:]) for z in zip(HostList, IPList, ExcelGroupName)}
```

> > > dict2
> > >       {'test1': ['1.1.1.1', 'test-group-1'], 'test2': ['2.2.2.2', 'test-group-2'], 'test3': ['3.3.3.3', 'test-group-3']}

Comment: Show the code you have so far, show a minimal example of your problem that people can run and help you resolve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's going to be very difficult to provide you with a good answer without more context about what exactly your end goal is for this data, but here are two ways you can consider structuring your data:

**A list of dicts:**

```
list_of_dicts = [
    dict(
        Hostname = ['test1', 'test2', 'test3',],
        IP = ['1.1.1.1', '2.2.2.2', '3.3.3.3',],
        GroupName = 'test-group-1',
        Port = [443, 22, 808, 80, 161],
    ),
    dict(
        Hostname = ['test4',],
        IP = ['4.4.4.4',],
        GroupName = 'test-group-2',
        Port = [443, 8080],
    ),
    dict(
        Hostname = ['test5', 'test6',],
        IP = ['5.5.5.5', '6.6.6.6',],
        GroupName = 'test-group-3',
        Port = [443],
    ),
]
print(list_of_dicts)
print(list_of_dicts[0])
print(list_of_dicts[0]["Hostname"])
print(list_of_dicts[0]["Hostname"][0])
```

**A dict of dicts using the GroupNames as keys:**

```
dict_of_dicts = {
    'test-group-1' : dict(
        Hostname = ['test1', 'test2', 'test3',],
        IP = ['1.1.1.1', '2.2.2.2', '3.3.3.3',],
        Port = [443, 22, 808, 80, 161],
    ),
    'test-group-2' : dict(
        Hostname = ['test4',],
        IP = ['4.4.4.4',],
        Port = [443, 8080],
    ),
    'test-group-3' : dict(
        Hostname = ['test5', 'test6',],
        IP = ['5.5.5.5', '6.6.6.6',],
        Port = [443],
    ),
}  
print(dict_of_dicts)
print(dict_of_dicts['test-group-1'])
print(dict_of_dicts['test-group-1']["Hostname"])
print(dict_of_dicts['test-group-1']["Hostname"][0])
```

[examples in python tutor](http://pythontutor.com/visualize.html#code=list_of_dicts%20%3D%20%5B%0A%20%20%20%20dict%28%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20Hostname%20%3D%20%5B'test1',%20'test2',%20'test3',%5D,%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20IP%20%3D%20%5B'1.1.1.1',%20'2.2.2.2',%20'3.3.3.3',%5D,%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20GroupName%20%3D%20'test-group-1',%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20Port%20%3D%20%5B443,%2022,%20808,%2080,%20161%5D,%0A%20%20%20%20%29,%0A%20%20%20%20dict%28%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20Hostname%20%3D%20%5B'test4',%5D,%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20IP%20%3D%20%5B'4.4.4.4',%5D,%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20GroupName%20%3D%20'test-group-2',%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20Port%20%3D%20%5B443,%208080%5D,%0A%20%20%20%20%29,%0A%20%20%20%20dict%28%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20Hostname%20%3D%20%5B'test5',%20'test6',%5D,%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20IP%20%3D%20%5B'5.5.5.5',%20'6.6.6.6',%5D,%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20GroupName%20%3D%20'test-group-3',%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20Port%20%3D%20%5B443%5D,%0A%20%20%20%20%29,%0A%5D%0Aprint%28list_of_dicts%29%0Aprint%28list_of_dicts%5B0%5D%29%0Aprint%28list_of_dicts%5B0%5D%5B%22Hostname%22%5D%29%0Aprint%28list_of_dicts%5B0%5D%5B%22Hostname%22%5D%5B0%5D,'%5Cn'%29%0A%0Adict_of_dicts%20%3D%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20'test-group-1'%20%3A%20dict%28%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20Hostname%20%3D%20%5B'test1',%20'test2',%20'test3',%5D,%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20IP%20%3D%20%5B'1.1.1.1',%20'2.2.2.2',%20'3.3.3.3',%5D,%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20Port%20%3D%20%5B443,%2022,%20808,%2080,%20161%5D,%0A%20%20%20%20%29,%0A%20%20%20%20'test-group-2'%20%3A%20dict%28%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20Hostname%20%3D%20%5B'test4',%5D,%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20IP%20%3D%20%5B'4.4.4.4',%5D,%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20Port%20%3D%20%5B443,%208080%5D,%0A%20%20%20%20%29,%0A%20%20%20%20'test-group-3'%20%3A%20dict%28%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20Hostname%20%3D%20%5B'test5',%20'test6',%5D,%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20IP%20%3D%20%5B'5.5.5.5',%20'6.6.6.6',%5D,%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20Port%20%3D%20%5B443%5D,%0A%20%20%20%20%29,%0A%7D%20%20%0Aprint%28dict_of_dicts%29%0Aprint%28dict_of_dicts%5B'test-group-1'%5D%29%0Aprint%28dict_of_dicts%5B'test-group-1'%5D%5B%22Hostname%22%5D%29%0Aprint%28dict_of_dicts%5B'test-group-1'%5D%5B%22Hostname%22%5D%5B0%5D%29&cumulative=true&curInstr=35&heapPrimitives=false&mode=display&origin=opt-frontend.js&py=py3anaconda&rawInputLstJSON=%5B%5D&textReferences=false)

Also if you already have this data in excel then I would highly recommend looking into using [pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/) to [read](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html) this data into a [DataFrame](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.html).

Comment: That sounds good that I can atleast group each row into a dict entry with Group name as the Key. How do I do that in a code.I am using excel to pull the data in with pandas

Comment: So if you are using `pandas.read_excel` to get your data into python, I personally wouldn't bother with trying to build a `dict` out of this data. When you load this data in with pandas it will be in a `DataFrame` object that has a method available for doing just about anything and everything you could possibly want to do with this data. That being said if you really want to move this data from a df to a dict then I would play-around with [pandas.DataFrame.to_dict](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_dict.html)